# How to process the ajax data send from the datatable

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

I am getting an ajax error, while I am sending the data from the datatable, in order to perform some pre-processing task in the database.

[image: Datatable JS Code]

Using Codeingiter, so in controller I am accessing using the $_POST['request], $_POST[''name']. But its now working, I had also tried the $this->input->POST() of CI, but still not working.

Don't know what's wrong with the ajax within the datatable?

Comment: Please add your code here, it's easy for the community to answer.

Comment: Please don't post code as an image but rather as code-formatted text since none of us can copy, paste and run 

an image. For more on this, please see 
[**Why may I not upload images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-

images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) 
on SO when asking a question?. Also please check out the 
[**How to Ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more on site best-practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->input->POST()` should be small letter `$this->input->post()`.

Comment: Thank You now its now giving ajax error, but instead its now giving json invalid response. I have debugged through network, it show me this kind of error present in my controller file   $_POST['draw'] i.e all the datatable elements that i need to use and update is giving me the json invalid error. How to overcome this issue.

Comment: Problem solved ?

Comment: Ya the inital ajax data are being read by the contoller, but the datatable other attributes are now giiving error of invalid json response